# Amazon AWS ECS Task delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm using to Run Task on AWS ECS for batch tasks.

Sometimes it takes 10 seconds for the task to be on pending start and move to running status and sometimes it can take 5 minutes to start running
between pending status to start running.

What can i do in order to prevent the 5 minutes delay issues?
Is there some settings or kind of "warm up" procedures?

Comment: It should not take so long to run a task, when you change the images you have to do the pull. If the image is too heavy, it can affect the response time. Did you check that out?

Comment: Yes, my image size is not small ~1giga but yet most of the times it takes up to 10 seconds to start running and sometimes i faced the issue of 1.5-5 minutes delay. It's a real major gap between the same image running.

Comment: Another possibility might be to schedule the task for a bit earlier than intended, and add a delay to your script, for example in PHP using [time_sleep_until](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php)

Answer (score 1):

The delay is due to your task starting on a container instance that doesn't have your base image already downloaded.  There are a few things you can do to help with this:

1. Pre-load your instances by starting *n* number of tasks simultaneously, where *n* is the number of instances you have in your cluster. This will download your images onto each container instance, which will drastically improve the start times of subsequent tasks.
2. Improve the networking throughput of your instances, by upgrading to larger instances with higher throughput.  You can see a breakdown of each instance type on [the 'Amazon EC2 Instance Configuration' page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html).  You need to weigh up the increased cost against the delay.
3. Reduce your image size.

Comment: Another thing I would add is to use a base image. Most likely the 1 GB image is made up of something like 500 MB of base OS, and 250 MB of system libs that are common to all versions of your container. You can prebake these as a base image that is reused across all your containers, so that each time your deploy a task you only have to pull down the ~250 MB of custom code that is actually different in that revision. That can greatly speed up task launches.